# how can I change a variable I added to the kernel from an LKM?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am starting learning with a very basic "hello world" LKM, plus I have added functionality to the kernel and successfully recompiled and it works.
What I like to do now is add a variable to the compiled kernel code, then from my LKM be able to change that variable when I load and unload module. This way I can start and stop the kernel functionality without recompile.
any suggestion?

thank you

Comment: Why not add it to proc and/or sysfs instead?

Comment: what do you mean? How would I do that? thanks for help.

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html#AEN769

Comment: I noticed in the file where I added code, there are lots of #ifdef #endif sections. So I figure it easiest to just set a variable like MY_MODULE_LOADED but I don't know how to change MY_MODULE_LOADED from my LKM

Comment: `#ifdef` only works at compile time. You cannot change their values at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions :
1) expose the variable to userspace via proc/sysfs (preferred way)
2) use a character device driver to send an ioctl.